# How to send out plain XML in SOAP response?

Tags: php, soap, encoding, soapserver

I'm using PHP SoapServer class and try to put plain XML inside the body of the SOAP response.

**Case 1:**

My WSDL has

```
<element name="getDataResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
```

I encode the response

```
return new SoapVar($my_xml,XSD_ANYXML)
```

PHP SoapClient says

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules
```

**Case 2:**

WSDL

```
<element name="getDataResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
```

response encoding

```
return new SoapVar($my_xml,XSD_STRING)
```

response XML has all < encoded as &lt; and > as &gt;

**Case 3:**

WDSL

```
<element name="getDataResponse">
  <complexType>
   ... 
  </complexType>
</element>
```

where complexType corresponds the structure of XML to return

response encoding

```
return new SoapVar($my_xml,XSD_ANYXML)
```

now return type is an object, not XML string

**Case 4**

same as case 3 except encoding as SOAP_ENC_OBJECT. Again result will be object.

Please help! How can I get just plain XML text as body of the SOAP response?

Comment: You could try to recursively apply `new SoapVar()` on your actual data structure instead of writing the XML in a string.

Comment: Yes, but the question was that **if I want to write out XML as a string**, how can I do it.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?

```
return new SoapVar(
     '<ns1:xmlDocument>'.$my_xml.'</ns1:xmlDocument>',
     XSD_ANYXML
);
```

There are other solutions as well [at this PHP page](http://php.net/manual/soapvar.soapvar.php). (See 'User Contributed Notes' section)

Comment: This will return NULL since the name of the return message in WSDL is not xmlDocument. `$xmlvar = new SoapVar('<ns1:getDataResponse>'.$xmlDocument.'</ns1:getDataResponse>',XSD_ANYXML);` will lead to case 1.